# Add email hyperlink to spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet where I track incoming email questions and outgoing responses.  As questions come in, I have a script that appends a row (using `.appendRow()`) with information in the first few cells.  To make sending the responses easier, I would like to include the email address of the questioner as a hyperlink in one cell of the new row.  I've tried using `=HYPERLINK(...)` and get a syntax error.

Comment: According to the [support docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313/?hl=en&authuser=0), `mailto:` links are allowed. What's the syntax you're using? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: I got it to work by concatenating mailto: with the email address e.g. str1 = new String ('mailto:'); str2 = name@gmail.com; mailString = str1.concat(str2);

Comment: Great! You should create an answer with that information and, when you can, "accept" it. That way when someone runs into the same difficulty in the future, they'll be able to find your post and how you fixed it.

Comment: As a beginner on this site, I don't have a clue as to how to post a "good looking" answer.

Comment: Just do the best you can. There's [editing help](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help) available.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to make this work.  It would be nice not to have the "mailto" show up, but this way does provide the correct functionality.

```
var string1 = new String ('mailto:');  
var string2 = joeblow@gmail.com;  
var address = string1.concat(string2);  
    sheet.appendRow(["", xxxx, yyyy, address]);
```